# Trying to implement an incrementer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have successfully implemented an incrementer app that shows a number with a + and - on each side. When either is clicked, the number goes up or down respectively. But because if statements work differently in jsx I am having trouble setting limits for the number, such as not going below zero.

I have tried putting in if statements but they don't work. How can I make it for instance so if the + or - is clicked once the number reaches a certain min or max value it doesn't change?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      num: 1
    }
    this.addNum = this.addNum.bind(this)
    this.minusNum = this.minusNum.bind(this)
  }

  addNum() {
    this.setState({

      num: this.state.num +1
    }, function() {
      console.log('number of issues is ' + this.state.num)
    })
  }

  minusNum() {
    this.setState({



      num: this.state.num - 1
    }, function() {
    })
  }
`
  render() { 
     return (
      <div>

     <body>

      <div className="incrementer">
        <div>
            <h2 className="minus" onClick={this.minusNum}>-</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h2 className="number">{this.state.num}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>

              <h2 className="plus" onClick={this.addNum}>+</h2>

            </div>
      </div>

      </body>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: please choose the answer, that best solves your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement your own logic to control edge cases which you don't want to happen.

Here is your code with additional functionality and ES6 arrow functions (without bind).

To change max and min numbers just edit `minValue` and `maxValue`

```
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        num: 1
    }

    minValue = 0
    maxValue = 10

    addNum = () => {
        const { num } = this.state

        if (num < this.maxValue) {
            this.setState({ num: num + 1 }, this.log)
        }
    }

    minusNum = () => {
        const { num } = this.state

        if (num > this.minValue) {
            this.setState({ num: num - 1 }, this.log)
        }
    }

    log = () => {
        console.log('number of issues is ' + this.state.num)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="incrementer">
                <div>
                    <h2 className="minus" onClick={this.minusNum}>
                        -
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2 className="number">{this.state.num}</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2 className="plus" onClick={this.addNum}>
                        +
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the bounds of the variable in your addNum and minusNum methods.

There are no “inbuilt” ways to implement state constraints in React.js (in the way one might with e.g. a database column).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check in your minus function, if the current value in state is zero, do nothing.

```
this.state = {
  num: 1,
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 10
}

minusNum() {
  if (this.state.num === this.state.minValue) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({
    num: this.state.num - 1
  }, function() {})
}

addNum() {
  // assuming you have maxValue in state 
  if (this.state.num > this.state.maxValue) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({

    num: this.state.num + 1
  }, function() {
    console.log('number of issues is ' + this.state.num)
  })
}
```